# How to scrape table from website, while BS4 selection won`t find it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using below code scrape table element from url ([www.sfda.gov.sa/en/cosmetics-list](http://www.sfda.gov.sa/en/cosmetics-list)). But its coming empty

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url="https://www.sfda.gov.sa/en/cosmetics-list"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-striped display'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

res = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    if row:
        res.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["ProductName", "Category", "Country", "Company"])
print(df)
```

Running above code but not getting data

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded via XHR so you should use this to get your information:

```
url = 'https://www.sfda.gov.sa/GetCosmetics.php?page=1'
pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url).json()['results'])
```

##### Example

Loop over number of pages in [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) and collect all data.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = []

for i in range(1,5):
    url = f'https://www.sfda.gov.sa/GetCosmetics.php?page={i}'
    data.extend(requests.get(url).json()['results'])

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | id | cosmatics_Id | productNotificationsId | productNumber | status | productArName | productEnName | brandName | catArabic | catEnglish | counrtyAr | counrtyEn | manufactureType | packageVolume | unitAr | unitEn | barcode | manufacturearabicname | manufactureenglishname | listedNameAr | listedNameEn | imageUrl | batchNumber | country_of_manufacturing_English | country_of_manufacturing_Arabic | productCreationDate | productexpireddate | subCategory1 | subCategoryAR | storageCircumstances | protectionInstructions | usageInstructions | notes | mainCommercialRecordNumber | manufacturingLicenseNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 549105 | 58472 | 10518 | 2020-011019101291-245945 | Active | ليتسيا كوبيبا | Litsea cubeba oil | MOKSHA LIFE STYLE | منتجات العناية بالبشرة | Skin products | الهند | India | Foreign | 250 | ملي لتر | Milliliter (ml) | 0 | موكشا لايف ستايل برودكت | Moksha lifestyle products | مؤسسة شجور الارض للتجارة | shojoor alearth trading |  |  | India | الهند | 2020-09-28T09:40:46 | 2025-10-05T09:40:46 | Perfumes | العطور | room temperature | تاريخ انتهاء الصلاحية | الاستعمال الخارجي |  | 7016000957 | FR555666 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | 84386 | 58481 | 4031 | 2016-0120132-048982 | Active | جودي ثيرابي سيستيم للشعر بالبروتين | Judy protein & Silk hair therapy system | Judy | منتجات العناية بالشعر وفروة الرأس | Hair and scalp products | الولايات المتحدة | United States | Foreign | 1000 | ملي لتر | Milliliter (ml) | 641243925950 | معامل ناتيورال كوزماتيك | natural cosmetic labs USA Inc., | شركه بيت جودي الدوليه للتجارة | bait gody for trading co. |  |  | United States | الولايات المتحدة | 2016-12-25T14:40:44 | 2027-01-01T14:40:44 | Hair styling products | منتجات تصفيف الشعر |  |  |  |  | 7007289163 | FR555666 |

Comment: Thanks its working!! Any idea how to loop through all pages ?

Comment: Sounds great - There is an example how to loop in my answer, may take a read of https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range, this is the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concurrent.futures to concurrently scrape pages and when all pages are complete concat the results into a single dataframe:

```
import concurrent.futures
import json
import os

import pandas as pd
import requests


class Scrape:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root_url = "https://www.sfda.gov.sa/GetCosmetics.php?"
        self.pages = self.get_page_count()
        self.processors = os.cpu_count()

    def get_page_count(self) -> int:
        return self.get_data(url=self.root_url).get("pageCount")

    @staticmethod
    def get_data(url: str) -> dict:
        with requests.Session() as request:
            response = request.get(url, timeout=30)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(response.raise_for_status())

        return json.loads(response.text)

    def process_pages(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        page_range = list(range(1, self.pages + 1))

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.processors) as executor:
            return pd.concat(executor.map(self.parse_data, page_range)).reset_index(drop=True)

    def parse_data(self, page: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
        url = f"{self.root_url}page={page}"
        data = self.get_data(url=url)

        return (pd
                .json_normalize(data=data, record_path="results")
                )[["productEnName", "catEnglish", "counrtyEn", "brandName"]].rename(
            columns={"productEnName": "ProductName", "catEnglish": "Category",
                     "counrtyEn": "Country", "brandName": "Company"}
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    final_df = Scrape().process_pages()
    print(final_df)
```

Comment: @Baker Last page number is 84067.How to pass range 1 to 84067 in above code

Comment: edited key for page count. No need to pass specific page range as it does it for you.

Comment: You should except the answers if they answered your question so other users know it's solved. Also consider upvoting if you found an answer useful.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I m getting below error None: Max retries exceeded with url: /GetCosmetics.php?page=8776 (Caused by None)

Comment: You might be getting throttled from hitting the website api so many times. maybe look into rotating proxies or find the robot.txt on the website see if their is a tps limit.

Comment: Website using robot.txt but limit is not mentioned in it